# how to pause/ resume a subprocess in another route in python flask

Tags: python, flask, subprocess, python-multithreading

There are 3 routes to start , stop and resume library via main. can i know how resume/restart the library .
main file is from this link :[https://github.com/fhamborg/news-please/blob/master/newsplease/**main**.py](https://github.com/fhamborg/news-please/blob/master/newsplease/__main__.py)

code is this:

```
@app.route('/start', methods=["GET","POST"])
def start_page():
    try:
        global j
        j = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files (x86)\python\python.exe",r"C:\Program Files (x86)\python\New folder\main\training\news-please-master\news-please-master\newsplease\__main__.py","-c newsplease/config"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell = True)
        return "0"
    except:
        return "1"


@app.route('/stop', methods=["GET","POST"])
def stop_page(): 
    try:
        p = subprocess.call(['taskkill', '/F', '/T', '/PID', str(j.pid)])
        if p == 0:
            return "0"
        else:
            return "1"
    except NameError:
        return "1"

@app.route('/resume', methods=["GET","POST"])    
def resume_page():
    try:
        j.poll()
        i = j.poll()
        if (i == None):
            return "0"
        else:
            return "1"     
    except NameError:
        return "1"
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port= 5000, debug = True)
```

routes values are given here in the picture.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMNSW.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMNSW.png

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can forget about global variables in this context (globals will NOT work as expected in a multi-user and multi-process setup, which is the typical case for wsgi apps).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers iam new to python. is there any another way?

Comment: Note that this is actually not a python issue by itself, but a by-product of the way wsgi apps are deployed. A global is per-process (and doesn't "belong" to a given user), but the app is used by concurrent users and served by multiple processes, so you cannot safely use a global to store data that are per-user and/or must be shared between server processes. That's why web applications use sessions (to keep per-user data) and (if well designed) use a shared data store for session data (so all server process get the same, up to date session data).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers so i have to use request library to solve this problem?

Comment: Why ??? This is totally unrelated, requests is a client lib.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers okay. so which library to use?

Comment: Have you read my comment ? "That's why web applications use sessions (to keep per-user data) and (if well designed) use a shared data store for session data (so all server process get the same, up to date session data)".

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers okay got it.